# Python How to call a method from inside another method

Tags: python, oop, scipy

I am a new OOP. I have written the following classes and methods and want to call a method from inside another method.  However, I get an error saying name polynomial (method) is not defined. Any ideas why?

```
#Imports
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from scipy import optimize

class MaxImpact():
    def __init__(self,X,Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.minima_index = argrelextrema(self.Y,np.less)
        self.maxima_index = argrelextrema(self.Y,np.greater)
        self.approx_converge_pt = []
        self.approx_converge_idx = []

    # .... (bunch of other methods)

    def calc_convergePt_X(self):
        for i in range(1,len(self.Y)):
            if (self.Y[i-1] < 0 and self.Y[i] > 0) or (self.Y[i-1] > 0 and self.Y[i] < 0):
                self.approx_converge_idx.append(i-1)         

        for i in self.approx_converge_idx:
            self.x_val = self.X[i]
            return(self.x_val)

    def polynomial(self):
        func = clf4.intercept_[0] + clf4.coef_[0][1] * self.X + clf4.coef_[0][2]*np.power(self.X,2) + clf4.coef_[0][3]*np.power(self.X,3) + clf4.coef_[0][4]*np.power(self.X,4)

    def neutral_state(self):
        sol = optimize.root(polynomial(),self.x_val)

maxImp2 = MaxImpact(XX,YY4)
print(maxImp2.calc_convergePt_X())
print(maxImp2.neutral_state())
```

Here I want to call the polynomial method which contains the polynomial eq within the neutral state method. I end up with the error "name polynomial is not defined"

Comment: Methods must be called *on an instance*, in this case ˋˋselfˋˋ.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi just use single backticks for `text formatting`, not doubles.

Comment: @Legorooj double backticks are ``fine``, but they must be the ˋcorrectˋ ones. My other keyboard doesn't have the correct ones.

Comment: ? Forgive me - I was unaware that they worked... No matter what type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods must be called on an instance. To call a method on the same instance, use `self` to refer to it:

```
def neutral_state(self):
    sol = optimize.root(self.polynomial(), self.x_val)
```

Comment: Thanks but I now I get this error " 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Comment: @imantha Since this is a separate issue, please ask a separate question. Your question code does not even use ``numpy.ndarray``.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Its all sorted. Just didn't know scipy optimize root function requires literally and equation. And I was passing it an numpy array.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Please accept the answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

please use `self` keyword while calling the class member.

`sol = optimize.root(self.polynomial(),self.x_val)`

Answer (score 1):

Python is raising a `NameError` because as far as it's concerned, `polynomial` doesn't exist. You've defined it as a method of the `MaxImpact` class, and therefore the function will only be called when you call `self.polynomial()`, telling python that it is part of the `MaxImpact` class.

Answer (score -2):

To call a method when using OOP in Python, and in this case, you can simply use `self.methodname()`

In your case:

```
class return_hello():
def polynomial(self):
    return print("hello")

def neutral_state(self):
    self.polynomial()
```